# Propagating touch events in a ScrollView

Tags: android

I'm having difficulty propagating touch events in my Android app. I have a ScrollView that contains a view that acts as an item. When you tap on the item, I want to handle an onclick event. This can be done by using setOnClickListener with the item. But I also need to intercept the scrollview's ACTION_UP and ACTION_DOWN events. I do that using the scrollview's setOnTouchListener.

The scrollview's ACTION_UP and ACTION_DOWN do not get received. I then decided to use a setOnTouchListener for the item intead of the setOnClickListener. This improves things. When you press down on the item, the item's onTouchListener does get called for ACTION_DOWN. I return false when exiting the item's onTouchListener. Then the scrollview's onTouchListener then gets called and the ACTION_DOWN is received. Things seem to be going fine. It does puzzle me though why the item's onTouchListener is called first instead of the scrollview's. I return false when exiting the scrollview's onTouchListener. Now when I release my finger, the scrollview's ACTION_UP is called and I return false.

The problem I have at this point is that the item's ACTION_UP is never called. I must have tried every combination of returning true/false in both onTouchListener's but am not able to get ACTION_UP to work, or if I do get it to work, then something in scrollview's onTouchListener no longer works.

I also tried adding dispatchTouchEvent in the scrollview's onTouchHandler but found that I get an endless recursive call.

Is there a way to have a scrollview AND its child item receive ACTION_UP / ACTION_DOWN?

Answer (score 0):

To have an item in a scrollview respond to onClick but also know when the user has tapped their finger down or up, requires some tricky coding. The solution here is available for API 15+. The key thing to note is that no onTouchListener is actually used for the scrollview. Instead, the events are detected on an item using the OnSimpleGestureListener. However, it is interesting to note that no onUp method exists for the OnSimpleGestureListener even though an onDown does (go figure). To solve for the onUp, you have to test for the return value of onTouchEvent:

```
GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetectorListItem());

listItem.setOnTouchListener(this.onTouchArticleItem);

private View.OnTouchListener onTouchArticleItem = new View.OnTouchListener()
{
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
  {
    try
    {

      boolean state = gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

      if ((event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) && !state)
      {
        // Handle up event here.
        return true;
      }
      else if ((event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && state)
      {
        // Handle down event here.
        return true;
      }
      else
        return state;


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Logger.Log(context, ex.getMessage(), Log.ERROR);
      return false;
    }
  }
};


private class GestureDetectorListItem extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
{
  public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e)
  {
    return true;
  }

  public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e)
  {
  }

  public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e)
  {
    return false;
  }

  public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e)
  {
    return false;
  }

  public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e)
  {
    return false;

  }

  public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e)
  {
  }

  public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e)
  {
    return true;
  }


  public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, final float distanceX, float distanceY)
  {
    return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
  {
    return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
  }
}
```

The only issue I see with this solution is if the scrollview has too few items to scroll. If there are too few items and the user presses somewhere on the scrollview other than an item, then no up/down events get detected. Whether that is important in your app or not is something you'll have to decide. If it is required, then maybe including an onTouchListener for the scrollview is also needed.